# Error when running VBA to save sheets as CSV

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in a workbook that saves selected sheets in a workbook as separate csv files. I thought this was working fine but I now seem to be getting the error message below, I'm not sure if I've inadvertently changed something, as I was trying to write a separate macro to run this one from another workbook.
Error message:

> Run time error '1004'
> Cannot access read-only document ' Activity.csv'

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv3()

'save workbook before continuing
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'save each sheet as csv
 Dim WB As Workbook
 Dim WS As Worksheet
 Dim FolderPath As String
 Dim FileName As String

'folder path for saving
 FolderPath = Range("B3").Value
 
'loop through all sheets
 For Each WS In Worksheets
 
'ignore these sheets
 If WS.Name <> "Control" And WS.Name <> "Summary" Then
    
'copy current sheet
     WS.Copy
     Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
     
'save as csv file
     FileName = WS.Name
     WB.SaveAs FileName:=FolderPath & "\" & FileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     WB.Close
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End If

 Next WS

End Sub
```

Comment: Change everything `Active`, e.g. `ActiveWorkbook` with `This`, e.g.  - `ThisWorkbook`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/35864330#35864330

Comment: `Range("B3").Value` really needs a workbook and worksheet qualifier.

Comment: Thank you both.  I think the main issue was the range not having a defined sheet as I realised I was testing the macro from a different sheet.  I'm still learning VBA, what difference does 'Active' to 'This' make.